# Exception in asyncore on file access when detached as daemon

Tags: python, asyncore, python-daemon

I have written an email server using the asynchat and mailbox modules from Python 2.7.  When running in the forground everything works fine and is stable over long periods of testing.  However, when detached as a daemon, access to the mailbox causes an exception in asyncore.loop() for a bad file descriptor.  Only the file access is a problem.  Socket I/O continues to work just fine.

It doesn't seem to matter whether the file is opened in `__init__()` or later in the found_terminator() function.

I'm detaching the process using the code from Schroeder's ActiveState recipe 278731 but using separate daemon modules does not change the symptom.

Here is a bit of pseudo code to show the flow:

```
createDaemon()
s = myServer() # subclass of asynchat.async_chat
dropPermissions #setuid nobody
asyncore.loop()
```

Here is the strace output when things blow up:

```
open("/tmp/MailboxDir/cur/1462562219.M374224P24795Q1.i7", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 8
fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=36, ...}) = 0
...
...
read(8, "To: you\nFrom: me\nSubject: test\n\n"..., 8192) = 36
read(8, "", 4096)                       = 0
read(8, "", 8192)                       = 0
close(8)                                = 0
...
stat64("/tmp/MailboxDir/cur/1462562219.M374224P24795Q1.i7", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=36, ...}) = 0
send(7, "+OK POP3 server ready\r\n", 23, 0) = 23
select(8, [4 5 6 7], [], [4 5 6 7], {30, 0}) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
```

The elided portions involve loading parser.py and feedparser.py modules which themselves open and close several file descriptors using mmap2.

So the email file's fd is closed <strike>but shortly after, that fd shows up in the select list.  It's not clear to me how the fd is added to the asyncore channel map or why it's still there after the close()</strike>.  It is not clear to me which of the fd is now invalid.  Nor is it clear why this doesn't happen when running in the shell process.

If I were using threading I can see this happening but I've done a quick look through the imported modules and don't see anything to indicate that they launch separate threads or processes.  Also, the behavior doesn't change if I continue to run as root instead of dropping to nobody.

Surely the asyncore and mailbox modules are used in other daemons.  I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the the email package was closing file descriptor 4 regardless of whether it owned it or not.  In my instance, fd 4 was always assigned to the log file.  I verified by opening a text file that was assigned fd 4 and and pushed the log file to fd 5.  The text file fd was closed during the processing of the first email message read from the mailbox.

Trying to debug the email package was taking up too much time so I wrote a replacement sufficient for my needs and got on with my work.